# Homotopy class of maps between orientable surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

Let $\Sigma_g$ denote the orientable surface of genus $g$.  I am interested in the set of maps $\Sigma_g \to \Sigma_h$ considered up to homotopy $[\Sigma_g, \Sigma_h]$.  I know when $g=h=0$ that these maps are just classified by degree.  Is there a concrete set of things that I can compute that tells me wether two maps $f,g : \Sigma_g \to \Sigma_h$ are homotopic?

I would also be interested in finding (based) maps $f,g: \Sigma_g \to \Sigma_h$ that are not homotopic but such that $\pi_1(f) = \pi_1(g)$.

Comment: look at a primer on mapping class groups

Comment: @max I don't think OP needs to go for primer , because he is not asking for clarifying all homeomorphism... He is only interested when two maps induced same map into fundamental level.

Comment: primer includes in particular a criterion for determining when two self-homeomorphisms are homotopic. one selects a suitable (finite) collection of curves and must check if the induced action on the curves coincides.

Comment: also the dehn-nielsen-baer theorem for based surfaces is discussed

Comment: @max read the last paragraph of that question, for answering that you don't need anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surfaces of genus $>0$ are classifying spaces of discrete groups (because their universal covers are contractible). Hence, two (based) maps between them are homotopic iff they induce the same homomorphism on fundamental groups.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the paper

Ellis, G.~J.
"Homotopy classification the J.H.C. Whitehead way".
*Exposition. Math.* **6** (2) (1988) 97--110.

Here is a  [pdf](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/Ellis-homclass.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

If $h\neq 0$ then for any map $f$ with  $\pi_1(f)=0$ can be lifted to the universal cover ( which is contractible) and hence can be homotoped into a single point.

If $h=0$, then it is a sphere, and in case of sphere there is Hopf degree theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_theorem .